# Finding type of path using the Windows API

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm trying to find the type of file a path is. I have this for Linux::

```
    pathType CFilesystem::findPathType(const string& path) const
    {
        struct stat info;
        int status = stat(path.c_str(), &info);

        if(status == -1)
        {
            switch(errno)
            {
                case ENOENT: // A component of the path does not exist.
                    return pathType::none;

                default:
                    return pathType::unknown;
            }
        }

        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
        {
            return pathType::directory;
        }

        if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
        {
            return pathType::file;
        }

        return pathType::unknown;
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to do the same for Windows. _stat doesn't seem to work (it says a file doesn't exist, even know I'm POSITIVE it exists. After all, the programming is running from it.

Comment: select isn't broken. (http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In windows, I think the function you are looking for is [`GetFileAttributesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You can also use the regular `_stat` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on windows as well though.  Are you including `sys/types.h` and `sys/stat.h`?

Comment: Instead of `_stat` I think you should use `_wstat64` for Unicode file name support and 64-bit times and sizes.

Comment: Thankyou! Will check out _wstat64 as well.

Answer (score 3):

`_stat` should work just fine.  I would try to find out what path your function is trying to resolve, printf-debugging or debugger-wise.  It must be something obvious.  (The result of the `printf`debugging can be appended to your question, next to a directory tree proving that the file *is* there :) )

Comment: Yeah, running it through the debugger a second time found my problem. It's because I forgot to implement another function when porting the engine. Stupid me.

Answer (score 3):

This has already been [solved for you](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/reference.html#Status-functions):

```
pathType CFilesystem::findPathType(string const &path) const {
  using namespace boost::filesystem;
  boost::filesystem::path p (path);
  switch (status(p)) {
    case directory_file:  return pathType::directory;
    case file_not_found:  return pathType::none;
    case regular_file:    return pathType::file;
    default:              return pathType::unknown;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jookia: Then use the code they do for this.  Just rip it out of their header and follow the license, which is one of the most liberal source code licenses you can find anywhere.  It's hard to write anything yourself which beats the solution given to you on a platter by an existing, tested, third-party library!

Comment: you should use `wstring` and `wpath` instead of `string` and `path`, otherwise Unicode paths won't work on Windows.